# Hiding contents of a TextBox in C# (Windows Store App)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Is it possible to do this? In Windows Forms, you would use the PasswordChar property, but when I type `passwordTextBox1.`, Visual studio doesn't show this property in auto-completion list. Is there an equivalent property, or I need to use the PasswordBox class?

I am using Visual studio 2013 Express for Windows 8.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [PasswordBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.aspx) for your needs.

You use it like this:

```
<PasswordBox Name="MyPasswordBox" Height="35" Width="400" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a PasswordBox control.

[details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.aspx)